# SSL connect using node js

Tags: node.js, openssl

I have the following openSSL connect that works.

openssl s_client -connect nfapi.netfonds.no:8400

I am trying to implement this simple connect in Node js with this. However I can't get it to connect to the server. None of the below .on functions get called.

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io.connect("nfapi.netfonds.no:8400", { secure: true, reconnect: true, rejectUnauthorized: false });


socket.on("connect", function(){
    console.log("connected");
});

socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    console.log("disconnected");
});

socket.on("error", function() {
    console.log("Error");
});

socket.on('event', function(data){
    console.log("data: " + data);
});
```

Comment: I think you need to setup your `nfapi.netfonds.no:8400` server with https on port `443` and pass it to the `socket.connect` function as first argument to make this work. I mean the server instance, not just the url.

Comment: It's not my server. It's an external service that I am trying to connect to.

Comment: Ah, I see. As far as I know you can not extend a server functionality without having control over it. So what you need is set up your own server.

Comment: No trying to extend it. Just connect to it